# unable botton when slider moves jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple slider that I need to disable the button at star and when user moves the slider it should be enabled, i can disable it at first but i cant to enable it back, for some reason it doesnt take the new variable value this is my code.
My thoughts its because the var is declared at first and the slider value is capsuled somehow?
but if that is the case how do i pass the value to the component?

```
    @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun PopupWindowDialogStudent(
    onConfirm: (Int, String) -> Unit,
    parentUiState: StudentHomeUiState,
) {
    // val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(parentUiState.showInAppFeedback) }
    val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(!parentUiState.showInAppFeedback) }
    var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(5f) }
    var enable by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val recommend = sliderPosition.toInt()
    Column(
    ) {
        Box {
            if (openDialog.value) {
                Dialog(
                    onDismissRequest = { openDialog.value = false },
                    properties = DialogProperties(),
                )
                {
                    Box(
                        Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(500.dp)
                            .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                            .border(1.dp, color = Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                    ) {
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .fillMaxHeight()
                                .padding(horizontal = 5.dp)
                                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                            ,
                            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                        ) {
                            Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                                Row(
                                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .fillMaxWidth()
                                        .padding(vertical = 10.dp)) {
                                    var completeValue by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
                                    completeValue = sliderPosition.toString()

                                    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally){
                                        Slider(
                                            value = sliderPosition,
                                            onValueChange = {
                                                sliderPosition = it
                                                var enable = true
                                            },
                                            valueRange = 0f..10f,
                                            steps = 9,
                                            onValueChangeFinished = {
                                                completeValue
                                            },
                                            modifier = Modifier.width(180.dp),
                                            colors = SliderDefaults.colors(
                                                thumbColor = secondaryColor,
                                                activeTrackColor = Color.Blue
                                            )

                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                                var comment by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
                                val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

                                TextField(
                                    value = comment,
                                    placeholder = { Text(text = "¿Tienes algún otro comentario?") },
                                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
                                    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                                        onDone = {keyboardController?.hide()}),
                                    onValueChange = {
                                        comment = it
                                    }
                                )
                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                                if (enable){
                                    Button(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .fillMaxWidth()
                                            .padding(10.dp),
                                        onClick = {
                                            onConfirm(recommend,comment)
                                            openDialog.value = !openDialog.value
                                        }
                                    ) {
                                        Text(
                                            text = "¡Contesta y gana +20 puntos!",
                                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2,
                                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                            modifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp))
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    Button(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .fillMaxWidth()
                                            .padding(10.dp),
                                        onClick = {
                                        }
                                    ) {
                                        Text(
                                            text = "¡Contesta y gana +20 puntos!",
                                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2,
                                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                            modifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp))
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Slider` you can use the `onValueChangeFinished` to change the `enable` value:

```
   var enable by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }                                 

   Slider(
        value = sliderPosition,
        onValueChange = {
            sliderPosition = it
            enable = true
        },
        onValueChangeFinished = {
            completeValue
            enable = false
        },
        //...
    )
```

Also you can avoid to use the `if` statement for the `Button`. Just use:

```
    Button(
        //...
        enabled = enable,
        onClick = {
            openDialog.value = !openDialog.value
        }
    ) {
        //...
    }
```